# Add and Maintain Leading Zeros for Zip Codes to CSV using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv, leading-zero

I have a csv file that is sent to me with Zip Codes that are formatted missing leading zeros. Some are in the five digit format, others are in the nine digit format, for which I need to not include the dash.

I need to add the leading zeros and save it as a csv that will maintain the leading zeros.

```
Columns(15).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

Dim ThisCell As Range
For Each ThisCell In Selection
    If Len(ThisCell) <= 5 Then
        ThisCell = "'" & Right("00000" & ThisCell, 5)
    Else
        ThisCell = "'" & Right("00000000" & ThisCell, 10)
    End If
Next ThisCell
```

Currently this does not maintain the leading zeros and causes the file to freeze and take a few minutes to load to the next step in the vba.

Comment: Try to avoid `selection` if possible.  Try a set range, so use a range like `for each ThisCell in Sheets("test").range("a1:a10000")`

Comment: Examine the CSV file with a text editor (eg Notepad or Notepad++). Is the CSV file really missing the leading zero's? Or is excel dropping them when you import the CSV file?  If the latter, then be sure to specify the imported zipcode column as being of type text (during the import process **before** it gets written to the sheet). And how are the 9-digit zipcodes formatted in the CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

In support of my comment, I would code something along these lines.  I would also check as Ron says, check where they are dropped before.

```
Sub TestPadding()

Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim c As Excel.Range

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestData").Range("a1:a10000")

For Each c In r.Cells
    c.value = "'" & PadString(c.Text)
Next c

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Function PadString(strInput As String) As String

Dim b As Boolean
Dim l As Byte

b = Len(strInput) < 5
l = IIf(b, 5, 10)

PadString = Right(String(l, "0") & strInput, l)

End Function
```